Using Reconcile function in r to model aggregate CPI from its components (Fabletools package for r)
I have CPI data that I am modeling using ARIMA for a given country. I also have data for the subcomponents (12 indices) and wanted to use Fabletools (hts) package to give me a reconciled forecast of my aggregate CPI from the subcomponents. So far using the reference, here , this is what I have :
Sample snippet of my data could be recreated using the following example (Although my data runs for 20 years of monthly data)
 df <- data.frame(
  year_month = c("2023-09-01", "2006-04-01", "2004-12-01", "2010-06-01", "2008-08-01",
                 "1998-11-01", "2002-10-01", "2008-09-01", "1999-04-01", "1998-05-01"),
  Index = c("Hotels Cafes", "Household Goods", "Education", "Housing", "Communiction",
            "Hotels Cafes", "Alcohol", "Transport", "Education", "Household Goods"),
  CPI = c(424.08, 106.73, 175.91, 257.31, 130.38, 117.97, 129.42, 192.50, 129.13, 103.76),
  cpi_weights = c(0.0431, 0.0561, 0.0193, 0.1442, 0.0492, 0.0431, 0.0717, 0.1522, 0.0193, 0.0561)
)

I then created a tsibble object with this code (where I compute weighted mean to aggregate the components):
  cpi_tsibble <- df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(CPI)) %>% 
  mutate(year_month = yearmonth(as.character(year_month))) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = year_month, key= Index) %>%
  aggregate_key(Index, CPI_weighted = weighted.mean(CPI, cpi_weights))

Then run Arima models and made forecasts using the code
cpi_tsibble |> filter(!is_aggregated(Index)) |>  
  model(arima1= ARIMA(CPI_weighted ~ 0 + pdq(1, 1, 1) + PDQ(0, 0, 0))) |>
  forecast()

Then I get something that looks like this



Index
.model
year_month
CPI_weighted
.mean




Education
arima1
2024 Jul
N(191, 160)
191.


Alcohol
arima1
2024 Nov
N(414, 84)
414.


Housing
arima1
2025 Jun
N(602, 2234)
602.


Health
arima1
2025 Jun
NA
NA


Hotels Cafes
arima1
2025 Sep
N(424, 643)
424.


Housing         arima1
2025 May
N(602, 2093)
602.



Household Goods
arima1
2025 Nov
N(177, 47)
177.


Housing
arima1
2024 Jun
N(602, 540)
602.


Communiction
arima1
2026 Jan
N(90, 80)
89.7


Alcohol
arima1
2025 Oct
N(428, 219)
428.



My question at this point is this: How can I then aggregate this data to give me one forecast for CPI aggregate (I had trouble using the function reconcile) ?

At this stage forecast reconciliation is only supported for aggregation (additive) constraints, and so reconciling a weighted mean is not yet possible.
